# ViewModels Property after PropertyChanged event is always Null

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, xamarin

This is my first experience with C#, as well as .net in general.    I'm trying to get an understanding of MVVM and how it can work with a screen I want to build.

My button text is not updating when I am changing it after a different button is clicked.  The debugger is showing that even though the OnPropertyChanged function is getting called, the PropertyChanged is always null.

I've looked at some documentation and taken a look at other posts of people asking similar questions but none of those solutions have worked for me.  I'm also looking for an explanation so I can understand what i'm doing wrong.

Code:

MonthViewPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="Mobile_Release_POC_4.MonthViewPage" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Mobile_Release_POC_4;assembly=Mobile_Release_POC_4"
             xmlns:telerikInput="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.Input;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.Input"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

            <ContentPage.BindingContext>
                 <local:WeekViewDatesViewModel MiddleWeekViewDate='{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}' />
            </ContentPage.BindingContext>

            <StackLayout>
               <Label Text="Monday, April 27, 2015"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>

               <Grid Padding="0" ColumnSpacing="-2">

                     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                           <RowDefinition Height="75" />
                     </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                     <Button x:Name="monthViewDateButton1"
                          Text="{Binding MiddleWeekViewDate}"
                          FontSize="10"
                          Grid.Row="0"
                          Grid.Column="0"
                      />
                     <Button x:Name="monthViewDateButton2"
                     Text="Tue 4/28"
                     FontSize="10"
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     Clicked="OnButtonClicked"
                     />

               </Grid>


         </StackLayout>
```

MonthViewPage.xaml.cs

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Mobile_Release_POC_4
{
public partial class MonthViewPage : ContentPage
{
    public MonthViewPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    void OnButtonClicked(object sender , EventArgs args){

        WeekViewDatesViewModel dc = new WeekViewDatesViewModel ();

        dc.MiddleWeekViewDate = new DateTime (2014, 2, 2);
    }
}
```

WeekViewDatesViewModel.cs

```
    namespace Mobile_Release_POC_4
{
    public class WeekViewDatesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        DateTime middleWeekViewDate;


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        public DateTime MiddleWeekViewDate
        {
            set
            {
                if (middleWeekViewDate != value)
                {
                    middleWeekViewDate = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("MiddleWeekViewDate");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return middleWeekViewDate;
            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this,
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Your button click creates a new view model *every time*, sets the value, and then throws it away. Of course this does not affect the completely other view model you are actually using as your data context. You should update that view model. And use commands to perform the data change *on the viewmodel* itself.

Comment: Ok yep that makes sense, and yea that was a big oversight by me.  So going off of that, how I make a change to the viewModel itself?  Some of the examples i've seen have involved using a DataContext, but I don't seem to have access to that currently.

Comment: That’s why I said use commands; you bind the button command to the view model, so a method gets executed on the view model instance itself. So you then have the instance of the view model as you are executing within the same. Search for `RelayCommand` or `DelegateCommand`.

Comment: Use Snoop to check your bindings at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Only create one ViewModel, its *scope* is the life of the page (at least).

Change your code to this:

```
public partial class MonthViewPage : ContentPage
{

    public WeekViewDatesViewModel VM { get; set; } 

    public MonthViewPage ()
    {
        DataContext = VM = new  WeekViewDatesViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    void OnButtonClicked(object sender , EventArgs args){

        VM.MiddleWeekViewDate = new DateTime (2014, 2, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the post.  It is telling me that DataContext does not exist in the current context.  I saw this example elsewhere but I don't have the ability to reference DataContext?

Comment: So it looks like since I'm doing a Xamarin.forms implementation maybe i'm supposed to be using BindingContext instead of DataContext?

Comment: @Kyle I have done windows phone, but not with Xamarin. The concept of the data context (in xaml (WPF/Silverlight/WP) is that every control along with the page has a context. If a context is not specified, then it inherits the parent's context all the way up to the page. I was simply setting the page's context to be the ViewModel which would eventually be accessed by the control in the above scenario.